# Control Applications Settings access

Tags: android, settings

I would like to regular Settings access.I am creating an app and user should not be able to uninstall it or Restore Factory Defaults without a password.

With android 2.3 it was not a problem but since HoneyComb...
The Settings UI changed and I don't know how do that now.

Before I used a service.

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: With the very limited exception of the device manager API, Android is intentionally designed not to let 3rd party applications do things like this.

Comment: Finally I restrict all settings access, with no difference between Application Settings, WifiSettings...
The Way is to use Service to check the package name of the activity at foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I restrict all settings access, with no difference between Application Settings, WifiSettings... The Way is to use Service to check the package name of the activity at foreground.